# When introducing myself, which should I use: "my name is" or "I am"?

Tags: comparison

It was raining and our extra classes were held after studying there was still some time left so I was talking to a girl I asked her what should we answere when someone ask us what's your name ?she told my name is but I told I am which is the right one

Comment: Informally , I think both are correct... But the former one follows the verbal pattern  of question asked ...

Comment: You might want to put some punctuation in that sentence. And, for your information, the verb tell is almost always followed by a noun or pronoun: tell me, tell you, tell us, tell Ankita. etc. "she told my name is" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of standard ways to introduce yourself, all of which are good in different scenarios:

What is your name?

- My name is Alex
- I am Alex
- It's Alex
- Alex

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but "My name is ..." is a bit formal and usually used in interview for example.

Comment: Why do you think it's a bit *formal*?  A little wordy, maybe, but the phrase occurs in [rap](https://www.vevo.com/watch/eminem/my-name-is/USIV20110017), in [children's books](https://www.amazon.com/Hi-Name-Jack-Christina-Beall-Sullivan/dp/0975971808), and on [stick-on name tags](https://www.staples.com/Avery-Print-or-Write-Name-Tags-HELLO-Red-Border-2-11-32-x-3-3-8/product_404285).